# How to Display output from snippet without using echo

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

The documentation on snippets in modx: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Snippets

Near the top of the doc it says:    ***Note how we returned the code rather than echo'ed the content out. Never use echo in a Snippet - always return the output.***

This doesn't display anything:

```
return $product_attribute $product_info[0][$column_name];
```

This does display:

```
echo $product_attribute $product_info[0][$column_name];
```

If I can't echo the content how do I get it to print in the html page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically means that you can `echo` the `returned` value rather than `echo` the value in the function itself. In OOP programming, echoing (or printing) to the screen is strictly monitored.

For example I have this function

```
function testExample($var) {
    return $var*2;
}
```

So when I need to echo it, I just need to

```
echo testExample(5);
```

Instead of this (bad practice)

```
function testExample($var) {
    echo $var*2;
}
```

The reason is that when you print value in the function, you can only use that function for printing the value, which isn't **reusable** at all. But by returning it, you can now use it for printing, or assigning to another variable or re-calculating on it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from the note, there is a convention not to use `echo` inside a function, but rather return the value and perhaps echo it afterwards.

Other printing posibilities would be:

`print $your_variable;`

or `die($your_variable);`

Comment: No idea why it says not to echo. Was hoping someone would know.

Answer (score 0):

`return` is used to return values from a function/method ect
The `snippet` functionality of modx is actually just a function/class wrapper.